# Two coffee mixture problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A coffee merchant mixes a dark roast coffee that costs \$10 per pound with a light roast coffee that costs \$7 per pound. Assuming the merchant wants to make a profit, which of the following are not possible answers for the cost per pound of the mixture?

(i) \$9.40 (ii) \$7.60 (iii) \$11.00 (iv) \$6.50 (v) \$8.50

I'm stumped, I searched for similar questions, no avail. please help.

Comment: He cannot sell it for less than it costs him. That's all you need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The per pound value of any mixture will lie between the values of the component parts of the mixture.

Comment: I see. I know this sounds stupid, but is their any specific notation, or inequality for this AC=V problem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by AC=V.

Comment: Nevermind, I think the book im using is just adds a bit of lesson gaps.  Thank you so much!

Comment: actually, I figured out the math. I just did not understand it XD, but what you told me made my work so much clear haha!